# MeasureOverride does not work on Canvas

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I need to change Rectangle size placed on Canvas, so I inherited [Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas.aspx) class to use MeasureOverride:

```
public class CustomCanvas : Canvas
{
    public CustomCanvas() : base(){}

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        Size canvasDesiredSize = new Size();

        foreach (UIElement child in Children)
        {
            child.Measure(new Size(300, 300));
            canvasDesiredSize = child.DesiredSize;
        }

        return canvasDesiredSize;
    }
}
```

And used it:

```
<local:CustomCanvas Width="500" Height="800" Background="Gray">
        <Rectangle Fill="AliceBlue" Height="100" Width="100"/>
    </local:CustomCanvas>
```

But after execution the rectangle still 100,100 size (as specified in XAML). When `child.Measure(new Size(300, 300));` executed `child.DesiredSize` shows 0,0. Something strange happens there.

I used [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.measure(v=vs.110).aspx) as reference.

Comment: I have tried to do absolutely the same on a Panel control and Rectangle is not visible at all, despite `child.DesiredSize` shows 100,100 (as in XAML).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that Width and Height override any size given in Measure().

Microsoft's documentation lacks important information regarding the data flow between Measure() and MeasureOverride().

The container calls `Child.Measure()`
`Measure()` calls `MeasureCore()`
`MeasureCore()` calls `MeasureOverride()`

Measure is a method of UIElement.
MeasureCore is a method of FrameworkElement, which inherits from UIElement.  MeasureOverride is a method of FrameworkElement. MeasureOverride gets overridden by the child.

`UIElement.Measure(avialableSize)` does the following before calling `MeasurementCore()`:

- throws exception if avialableSize IsNan, both for width and height
- if UIElement is collapsed, MeasureCore will not get called
- if the availableSize has not changed, MeasureCore will not get called, unless InvalidateMeasure was called before
- call InvalidateArrange

`FrameworkElement.MeasurementCore(availableSize)` does the following before calling `MeasureOverride()`:

- removes Margin from availableSize
- **enforces height, minHeight and maxHeight over availableSize and the same for the witdh properties**

after calling `MeasureOverride()`, `MeasurementCore()` adjusts the values returned by `MeasureOverride()` to calculate DesiredSize:

- DesiredSize must be within MinWidth and MaxWidth
- add margin to DesiredSize

after calling `FrameworkElement.MeasurementCore()`, `UIElement.Measure()` executes:

- throws exception if return width or height is Infinite
- throws exception if return width or height isNaN