# UWP Can not change DesiredSize in MeasureOverride

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a layout like below

```
public sealed partial class CustomLayout : Panel
{
   protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   {
       foreach (UIElement child in Children)
       {
           child.Measure(new Size(300, 200));
       }

       return availableSize;
   }

   protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
   {
       foreach (UIElement child in Children)
       {
           child.Arrange(new Rect(0,0, child.DesiredSize.Width, child.DesiredSize.Height));
       }

       return finalSize;
   }
}
```

Here is my xaml

```
<Grid>
    <layout:CustomRelativeLayout>
        <Button x:Name="btn1" Content="button1" FontSize="50"/>
    </layout:CustomRelativeLayout>
</Grid>
```

In MeasureOverride(), although I set Size(300, 200), but DesireSize of button is always

DesiredSize = {189,80}, Width = NaN

How to change DesireSize in MeasureOverride(). I saw the guildline, but everything is not as expected

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.measureoverride?view=winrt-22621

In addition,
The rectangle can not be displayed in this layout without setting the width and height, why? the DesignSize is not apply for rectangle?

Non-Display

```
<Grid>
    <layout:CustomRelativeLayout>
        <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Fill="Red"/>
    </layout:CustomRelativeLayout>
</Grid>
```

Display

```
<Grid>
    <layout:CustomRelativeLayout>
        <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100"/>
    </layout:CustomRelativeLayout>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Your question is similar to this thred https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25154902/measureoverride-does-not-work-on-canvas. What function do you want to implement in this Layout? If you only need to set the size of the child control, you can directly set the width and height of the child in `MeasureOverride`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a slight missunderstanding of what you expect DesiredSize to do. When the UI stack tries to render the elements, it first goes around asking the desired size of all controls by calling `MeasureOverride` (oversimplyfying here) and after this tells them the size they get and tell them to arrange by calling `ArrangeOverride`.

When `MeasureOverride` gets called, the controls tell **their** desired size, where most take into account the desired size of their children. If you override `MeasureOverride`, you tell the desired size of **your** panel, not the button contained. If you set `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` to `Strech` you would have the desired effect of the button trying to grow into that size. Just specifying the height and width on the button would also be an option and is a lot more simple than creating a panel.